# How to add time to my date object?

Tags: java, android

**How to add time to my date object which i select using DatePicker.** The date picker by default set's the time to `00:00:00` to my date object, i need to add the current system time to my date object.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
//int hours = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).getHours();
//int minutes = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).getMinutes();
//int seconds = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).getSeconds();
now.set(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
textDateField.setText(getDateAsString(now.getTime()));
```

I am using Date Picker and the click of the set button, i get the date displayed in the field, but the date object is without time. How can i append the time with my date object.

```
public static String getDateAsString(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    return format.format(date);
}
```

The above is what i tried, but it did not work.

Comment: Is the problem the formatting of the output?

Comment: @Keppil: no, my text field would show date alone, but when i send to service it should have date and time contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the time too displayed in your field, you can just add it to your `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
public static String getDateAsString(final Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    return format.format(date);
}
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/mm0crfpxggjzvd5yktndg, here is my pastie on what i am trying.... i am not getting the time its always 00:00:00 when i try to get it from date object.

Comment: Where do you get `00:00:00`? You are formatting it without time.

Comment: You can get the current time by simply instantiating new Date().
Date now = new Date(); And then use the above written method to format it.

Comment: i show it in a different place, where i try to get time from this date object. String time = localDateFormat.format(Utils.getDate(thisDateObject); // thisDateObject always has 00:00:00 regardless of we adding time to it.

Comment: Show us all the code included in your question please, we're playing a guessing game here.

Comment: It looks like you format the `Date` without time, and then use that `String` to create your next `Date`, losing all the time info.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, can u just tell me one thing... what is the date and time in this long(1368144000000)

Comment: `10 May 2013 02:00:00` according to my locale.